# Sequelize leaving some foreign keys and Working if reversed

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

##### Idea Behind

I have 2 models User and TodoGroup. The idea is that each user can be in many todo groups, where users can share todos. But also, I want each user to have his own private "Main" todo group, which is created by default as soon as he signs up.

So, my idea was that `User` model should have `MainTodoGroupId` column, which is `UNIQUE` among users.

##### The Problem

But when I tried to do this using `sequelize`:

```js
function setupModels(sequelize) {
    const Todo = require("./Todo.model")(sequelize),
        TodoGroup = require("./TodoGroup.model")(sequelize),
        User_TodoGroup = require("./UserTodoGroup.model")(sequelize),
        User = require("./User.model")(sequelize),
        Role = require("./Role.model")(sequelize),
        UserCreds = require("./UserCreds.model")(sequelize);
    const models = {
        Todo,
        TodoGroup,
        User_TodoGroup,
        User,
        Role,
        UserCreds,
    };

    // Relations

    TodoGroup.hasOne(User, { foreignKey: "MainTodoGroupId" });
    User.belongsTo(TodoGroup, {
        as: "MainTodoGroup",
        foreignKey: "MainTodoGroupId",
    });

    return models;
}

/**
 * calls `sync()` after setting models and relations
 * @param {*} sequelize
 */
async function syncModels(sequelize) {
    const models = setupModels(sequelize);
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true, logging:log.sequelize });
    return models;
}

// To run here
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_URI);
sequelize.authenticate().then(async () => {
    const models = await syncModels(sequelize);
});
```

It **doesn't create** the `MainTodoGroupId` in `Users` table or anywhere

While when I tried to reverse it as follows:

```js
User.hasOne(TodoGroup, {
    as: "MainTodoGroup",
    foreignKey: "MainUserId",
});
TodoGroup.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "MainUserId",
});
```

It **created** the `MainUserId` in `TodoGroups` table

##### Definitions

Where **User.model.js**

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require("sequelize");
const errors = require("../config/errors");

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    return sequelize.define("User", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isAlpha: { msg: errors.AlphaOnly("name") },
                notEmpty: { msg: errors.Missing("name") },
            },
            set(name) {
                const preparedName = name.trim().toLowerCase();
                this.setDataValue("name", preparedName);
            },
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: { msg: errors.AlreadyExists("email") },
            validate: {
                isEmail: { msg: errors.NotEmail("email") },
            },
        },
    });
};
```

and **TodoGroup.model.js:**

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require("sequelize");
const errors = require("../config/errors");

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    return sequelize.define("TodoGroup", {
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: { msg: errors.Missing("title") },
            },
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you comment `hasOne` in both cases and check which one of them worked properly?

Comment: @Anatoly Same. Only Second (reversed) One

Answer (score 0):

It Worked!!

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748750/sequelize-associations-not-generating-foreign-key#:%7E:text=Synchronize%20models%20individually%20using%20their%20sync%20method%3A) by @Anatoly, It just worked when I added one of:

```js
await models.User.sync({ alter:true });
// OR
await models.User.sync({ force:true });
```

after syncing all models in that line saying:

```js
sequelize.authenticate().then(async () => {
    const models = await syncModels(sequelize);
    // Added Here
});
```